# How to code simple Goomba-like AI for 3D Platformer?

Tags: unity, 3d, ai

I'm making a 3D Platformer and have an enemy similar to a Goomba in terms of AI. How do I get the enemy to walk around and then follow the player when they're in range?

Comment: Did you try implementing something like `if (nearPlayer()) followPlayer(); else patrolNormally();` ? If so what issues did you run into?

Comment: No I haven't yet. How do I implement it?